# How to write an array with groups in java?

Tags: java, arrays

Noob here,

How would I create groups in my array?

```
receipt[] re11 = {["Book", 12.49, 1, false, true],["Music CD", 14.99, 1, false, false]};
```

I know in javascript you can use  brackets like that but i just can't remember how to do in java.

Edit: 
Here are the rest of my classes. Sorry this will prob be a bit more help:

```
public class receipt {

private double price;
private Integer quantity;
private String itemName;
private boolean imported;
private boolean taxExemption;

private double basicTaxRate = .10;
private double importDuty = .05; 
private double grandTotal;

public receipt(){

}

public receipt(String newItemName, double newPrice, Integer newQuantity, boolean newImported, boolean newTaxExemption){
    itemName = newItemName;
    price = newPrice;
    quantity = newQuantity;
    imported = newImported;
    taxExemption = newTaxExemption;
}

//Accessors
public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}

public Integer getQuantity(){
    return quantity;
}

public String getItemName(){
    return itemName;
}

public boolean getImported(){
    return imported;
}

public boolean getTaxExemption(){
    return taxExemption;
}


//mutators
public void setPrice(double newPrice){
    //JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the price of the item?");
    this.price = newPrice;
}

public void setQuantity(Integer newQuantity){
    this.quantity = newQuantity;
}

public void setItemName(String newItemName){
    this.itemName = newItemName;
}

public void setImported(boolean newImported){
    this.imported = newImported;
}

public void setTaxExemption(boolean newTaxExemption){
    this.taxExemption = newTaxExemption;
}

public double computeTax(){
    if(imported == true){
        return price*(1+(basicTaxRate+importDuty));
    }
    else{
        return price*(1+basicTaxRate);
    }
}

public double computeTotal(){
    if (taxExemption = false){
        return computeTax()*quantity;
    }
    else
        return price*quantity;

}

public void computeGrandTotal(){
    grandTotal =+ computeTotal();
    //return grandTotal;        
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?!

Comment: Is `receipt` a class you have implemented?

Comment: Do you mean javascript?

Comment: Just copy paste my answer and run. it is full working code..

Comment: @ R.J The purpose of this is that it would return the price of the product given the quantity and the give a grand total of all.

@ Christian yes I have implemented this class.

@Nick G No I want to do this in java.

Comment: you did not got any solution yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do like that-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * 
 * @author manish
 *
 */

public class CustomArrayList {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<reciept> custReciept=new ArrayList<reciept>();
        custReciept.add(new reciept("Book", 12.55, true, false));
        custReciept.add(new reciept("Book2", 15.55, true, true));

        for(int i=0;i<custReciept.size();i++){
    System.out.println( custReciept.get(i).name);
    System.out.println( custReciept.get(i).price);
    System.out.println( custReciept.get(i).first);

    }

    }


}
class reciept{
    String name;
    double price;
    boolean first,second;

    public reciept(String name, double price, boolean first, boolean second) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

}
```

Copy Paste above code and enjoy..

Comment: I get: `[Thoughtworks.receipt@addbf1, Thoughtworks.receipt@42e816]'. Does this mean that it did not convert properly?

Comment: @PurePhoenix Please check now my code I edited it.. Just iterate arrayList using loop.

Comment: so, should the `custReciept.get(i).name` ref the String itemName in `custReciept.get(i).name`?

Comment: Yes check reciept class here I have declare name as a string so of-course it ref to String.

Comment: I think I have full fill your requirement and for this i have did some effort so please make my answer as correct and give me up-vote too.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand thats all no worries. I am throwing an error with the .name part though.

Comment: I have tested it there is no error in my code. Please check something wrong in your logic.

Comment: @ManishSrivastava: if your answer is suitable for the OP's question then it will be marked as an answer. and why have you inserted the call to `super()` in your constructor when it will automatically be done by the compiler?

Comment: @PurePhoenix : when `custReciept.get(i).name` is executed it returns the ith element in the custReciept ArrayList. then that objects' attribute (name in this case) is retrieved. it is similar to `Receipt rec = custReciept.get(i); System.out.println(rec.name);`. it is a bad practice to use default access for instance variables. make them private and use getters and setters.

Comment: @BlackPanther go through eclipse and create constructor using source it will automatically add super(). That's mean it is useful some how because eclipse developer will not do stupid and useless thing.

Comment: @ManishSrivastava : the OP  never asked what eclipse would do. go through the JLS and see in how many constructors the call to `super()` is written and i am pretty sure that people at Sun and oracle are not stupid to miss out **important** things. your call of super is redundant and doesn't clarify anything and thus useless.

Comment: and it is a bad practice to ask the OP to choose your answer as the answer. if it is apt and appropriate for the OP's problem, then they will decide what to accept.

Comment: @BlackPanther may be Oracle don't have any updated project and before some days ago eclipse also don't have but when I updated it to latest one now they provide us. And I think super() is useless here but not extra because JVM do it in background so if we do it already I don't think there we are going to waste any memory or something else. And second thing every one have their own coding style and standard. Thanks for  your suggestion, I will mind it next time.

Comment: @BlackPanther You are right dear demanding for accept my answer is wrong but when you think your answer is fulfill user requirement I think he should accept it. And he also accept in comments that it work but i have some error. And I have spent my time for this so I should accept for some point.

Comment: A standard is called a standard because it is followed by a community and not by individuals. When you are using an Interface declaring instance variables as public and final is redundant yet we do it for clarity. the same way what you have done here is redundant but it doesn't clear anything. I am not saying inserting `super()` is useless. im just saying inserting it in this piece of code is irrelevant. Thanks for looking into the suggestion.  Lost no love and No offense meant. cheers.. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40556/discussion-between-manish-srivastava-and-black-panther)

Comment: @ Manish Srivastava you got me on the right track and I used the framework that you provided. But if it wasnt for BlackPanther I prob would not have gotten to a good result. I found that using `receipt rec = (receipt) custReceipt.get(i);
     System.out.println(rec.itemName);` was the best option for me. The one change I had to make was to cast it. Thanks to the both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
Receipt[] re11 = {new Receipt("Book", 12.49, 1, false, true),new Receipt("Music CD", 14.99, 1, false, false)};
```

Comment: yes, but i also need to output it to this(or something similar): How would I get a println of this? something similar to this `code: System.out.println(re11.getItemName() + " $" + re11.getPrice() + " "+ re11.getQuantity() + " $" + re11.computeTotal());`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, in Java, you cannot natively do that.
If "receipt" is your own class, you will have to create instances of that.
Assuming that it has a constructor taking a String, a double, and int, and two boolean values, that would look something like that:

```
receipt[] re11 = {new receipt("Book", 12.49, 1, false, true),new receipt("Music CD", 14.99, 1, false, false)};
```

Comment: How would I get a println of this? something similar to this

     System.out.println(re11.getItemName() + "               $" + re11.getPrice() + "              "+ re11.getQuantity() + "              $" + re11.computeTotal());

Comment: You would probably override the toString() method. Then you can just do System.out.println(xyz) with any instance xyz of your class. In your overridden "String toString()" method, you would just return a String that you generate in the same way you did in your coment above. If you want to transform an array of instances to a string, you would just call <a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])">java.util.Arrays.toString</a> an provide the Array as input. The result of that method can be given to System.out.println

Answer (score 1):

by groups i assume you mean a class.

```
class Receipt {
 String item;
 Double price;
 int quantity;
 boolean a; //unsure what the true and false are in your context
 boolean b; //unsure what the true and false are in your context
}
```

you can then use it like this

```
Receipt[] rel1 = {new Receipt("Book", 12.49, 1, false, true),new Receipt("Music CD", 14.99, 1, false, false)};
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, arrays in Java are different from arrays in JavaScript. Arrays in JavaScript expand as needed but in Java they do not. Also, you cannot 'remove' an element from a Java array.

What you need is an `ArrayList<YourClass>` which is an expandable array. It also allows you to remove the element you want.

Coming to the topic of grouping the data. You will need your own class with the desired variables and methods defined. Then you put the objects of that class into an `ArrayList`

So you would have your class:

```
public class Receipt {
 String item;
 Double price;
 int quantity;
 boolean available; 
 boolean iDoNotKnowWhy; 
 //getters and setters
}
```

Then you will have an `ArrayList<Receipt>` where you add all the data you want.

```
ArrayList<Receipt> receipts = new ArrayList<>();
receipts.add(new Receipt(....)); // add a new receipt
receipts.add(new Receipts(....)); // another receipt
```